# Change NativeScript XML layout based on orientation

Tags: android, ios, telerik, nativescript

I have a question about **NativeScript** orientation (Landscape and Portrait).

Is it possible to check if the ***device orientation*** is landscape or portrait and based on that switch the XML layout file? For instance, use `lay.land.xml` for landscape and `lay.port.xml` for portrait.

Thank's for all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NativeScript already does this out of the box. Name your files `<file-name>[.<qualifier>]*.<extension>`

- `land` - orientation is in landscape mode
- `port` - orientation is in portrait mode

> Note: All qualifiers are taken into account when the page is loading. However, changing the device orientation will not trigger page reload and will not change the current page.

This is documented here: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/navigation#orientation-qualifiers

Comment: I don't know about you but the file doesn't switch on orientation change. Instead if I start the app in landscape mode, it will load landscape files and vice versa. Changing orientation doesn't change the XML file.